# what's the difference between password and passphrase

Tags: security, ssl, openssl

For private key file, it requires to be encrypted using pass phrase. I am wondering is there any difference between password and pass phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is different beyond semantics. "Password" implies that you should use only one word while "passphrase" implies you can use multiple words. I have never seen a place where the strict meaning is enforced though, the two terms are usually completely interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

As an example:

Password: abc@123!@#

Passphrase: This is the passphrase for CA.